# equi join with long DataStructure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have bunch of tables, below is the tables list:

- System_User
- Acc_Roles
- Acc_User_role_map
- Acc_Permission
- Acc_Role_Permission_Map
- Acc_Menu_Items
- Acc_SubMenu
- Acc_Menu

I will explain above tables fields and relation.

And my query goes here:

```
select acc_menu_items.* from acc_menu, acc_menu_items, acc_submenu, system_user, acc_user_role_map, acc_roles, acc_role_permission_map, acc_permission
where system_user.user_id=acc_user_role_map.user_id
and acc_user_role_map.ROLE_ID=acc_roles.id
and acc_roles.id=acc_role_permission_map.ROLE_ID
and acc_role_permission_map.PERMISSION_ID=acc_permission.id

and acc_permission.MENUITEM_ID=acc_menu_items.id
and acc_menu_items.menu_id=acc_menu.id

and acc_menu_items.SUBMENU_ID=acc_submenu.id

and system_user.USER_ID='userName' and acc_menu.menu_name='menuName';
```

My problem is when I run the above query its displaying empty.

In that query when i remove the table name "acc_submenu" and "acc_menu_items.SUBMENU_ID=acc_submenu.id"

And it is fine I am getting data, if I put the submenu list also I am getting empty.

If anything is unclear I will upload full data.

Any one have any ideas?

### **Edited**

Find the below image link

http://www.4shared.com/photo/2Ml256my/Untitled-1-copy.html

My query is:

```
select acc_menu_items.* from acc_menu, acc_menu_items, acc_submenu, system_user, acc_user_role_map, acc_roles, acc_role_permission_map, acc_permission
where system_user.user_id=acc_user_role_map.user_id
and acc_user_role_map.ROLE_ID=acc_roles.id
and acc_roles.id=acc_role_permission_map.ROLE_ID
and acc_role_permission_map.PERMISSION_ID=acc_permission.id

and acc_permission.MENUITEM_ID=acc_menu_items.id
and acc_menu_items.menu_id=acc_menu.id

and system_user.USER_ID='setupadmin' and acc_menu.menu_name='Administrator';
```

The query above is getting data, when I replace the 'Administrator' with 'MainMenu', its not working, please explain what is the problem?

What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps think about making use of left join on acc_submenu table

Comment: You also might think about rewriting your query to use ANSI join syntax, i.e. use `INNER JOIN` and similar constructs instead of using comparisons in the WHERE clause.  See [Oracle join documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#i2054012) and [Oracle SELECT docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065646).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Your second query using the explicit join syntax:

```
select ami.* 
  from acc_submenu
    -- MISSING JOIN CONDITION
  join acc_roles ar
    -- MISSING JOIN CONDITION
  join acc_user_role_map aurm
    on aurm.role_id = ar.id
  join system_user su
    on su.user_id = aurm.user_id
  join acc_role_permission_map arpm
    on ar.id = arpm.role_id
  join acc_permission ap
    on arpm.permission_id = ap.id
  join acc_menu_items ami
    on ap.menuitem_id = ami.id
  join acc_menu am
    on ami.menu_id = am.id
 where su.user_id = 'setupadmin' 
   and am.menu_name = 'Administrator'
```

As you can see you have some missing join conditions, which means you're doing a [Cartesian join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) on `acc_submenu` and `acc_roles`. I assume this is unintentional...

Your first query using the explicit join syntax:

```
select ami.* 
  from system_user su
  join acc_user_role_map aurm
    on su.user_id = aurm.user_id
  join acc_roles ar 
    on aurm.role_id = ar.id
  join acc_role_permission_map arpm
    on ar.id = arpm.role_id
  join acc_permission ap
    on arpm.permission_id = ap.id
  join acc_menu_items ami
    on ap.menuitem_id = ami.id
  join acc_menu am
    on ami.menu_id = am.id
  join acc_submenu as
    on ami.submenu_id = as.id
 where su.user_id = 'userName' 
   and am.menu_name = 'menuName';
```

All this seems massively over-complicated. If we work backwards using your posted data; you want everything from the table `acc_menu_items` where the `menu_name = 'MainMenu'`:

That would be:

```
select ami.*
  from acc_menu am
  join acc_menu_items ami
    on am.id = ami.menu_id
```

You also want to restrict this to `system_user.user_id = 'setupadmin'`, which is unfortunate for me as I now have to write a lot... there's no real reason to go for `system_user` by the way, unless you want everything where `name = 'pradeep'`.

Building this up one join at a time I get:

```
select ami.*
  from acc_user_role_map aurm
  join acc_role_permission_map arpm
    on aurm.role_id = arpm.role_id
  join acc_permission ap
    on arpm.permission_id = ap.id
    -- Now I'm stuck as there-s nothing else to join to
    -- however, for the sake of argument let-s assume that acc_permission
    -- does have menuitem_id and that that number is one of those
    -- specified
  join acc_menu_items ami
    on ap.menuitem_id = ami.id
  join acc_submenu as
    on ami.submenu_id = as.id
  join acc_menu am
    on am.id = as.menu_id
 where aurm.user_id = 'setupadmin'
   and am.menu_name = 'MainMenu'
```

As you can see there are less joins, which makes it clearer. There's also an assumption that I have not been able to verify. I have assumed that there exists a `menuitem_id` of  1123, 1125, 1127 or 1129 in `acc_permission`.

There's another subtle difference though. I am joining on `acc_submenu` *first* then `acc_menu` in order to get the query. This has also changed the join condition; which is no longer:

```
on acc_menu_items.menu_id = acc_menu.id
```

but

```
on acc_menu.id = acc_submenu.menu_id
```

This is the reason why you get no results; your join queries are incorrect.

---

Which leads me to a few points:

- As your second query demonstrates *not* using the explicit join syntax is an easy way to make errors. *It is not worth using the implicit join syntax*; especially when your queries have many joins or are complicated. They've been the SQL standard for a few decades now so you should be using them.
- When creating complicated queries it is often easier if you build them up one layer at a time. This means that you can verify whether the results you expect are being returned at each stage. If you go wrong, you can easily pinpoint where it occurred.

And some friendly advice, which you can ignore or not as you please:

Your schema is over-complicated; especially around the menu tables. Especially disconcerting is the fact that the join after `acc_menu_items` will have to be to one of two different tables and you won't know which. If it's possible to simplify this please do. For instance by adding a `parent_id` to `acc_menu` and moving the sub-menus in here. You can then remove the extra column on `acc_menu_items`.

#### Further Reading:

- [Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) - Wikipedia
- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) - Coding Horror

Answer (score 0):

Without to much thought: your line reading

```
and acc_menu_items.SUBMENU_ID=acc_submenu.id
```

implies that acc_menu_items.SubMenu_ID has a corresponding entry in Acc_submenu.id.  Do you have data that supports that assertion?

Meaning: in ACC_MENU_ITEMS.SubMenu_ID you have a record called "1" 
and in Acc_SubMenu.id you also have a record of the same data type called "1"  if not, then your logic if flawed.  based on your tests, it's likely the problem

Comment: yes you are right, i have a relation in acc_submenu
in my acc_menu_items has two realtions i.e., acc_menu and acc_submenu

Comment: Then if data exists, the only thing it could be is that the data doesn't exist for the `system_user.USER_ID='userName' and acc_menu.menu_name='menuName';` specified